# SQL Server: inserting data from one database to another database structure by specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help to pull data from one database into another database with a different schema I am writing a PHP script to achieve this.

My first query is:

```
SELECT orderid, customerid, validation_date, test_type, test_result, amount 
WHERE test_type IN ('ph', 'bh')
```

and I get the result as following

```
1 101001 10-01-2018 bh 5 20.00
2 101001 10-01-2018 ph 3 25.00
3 101002 11-02-2018 bh 4 20.00
4 101002 11-02-2018 ph 2 25.00
5 101003 15-02-2018 bh 3 20.00
6 101003 15-02-2018 ph 4 25.00
7 101001 25-04-2018 bh 4 20.00
8 101001 25-04-2018 ph 2 25.00
```

I want to insert this data into another SQL Server table of the structure in one line for each specific date.

The table schema of the other database is as follows:

```
itemid, customerid, validation_date, ph_value, bh_value
```

So I want the result to go into the database as follows:

```
1 101001 10-01-2018 3 5
2 101002 11-02-2018 2 4 
3 101003 15-02-2018 2 3 
4 101001 25-04-2018 2 4
```

Please can you advice on how I can achieve this using a SQL query? I did a select, AND NOW want to insert into the database in the above format

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Hi Shawn, I am selecting data from COGNOS and inserting in MS SQL.

Comment: Your result set has `itemid`.  But your data doesn't seem to have that column.  Also, does the target table already exist?

Comment: Hi Gordon, itemid is an auto increment id in the MS SQL table. Thank you, giving your answer a try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload your data to SQL Server "as is" and then use the SQL engine to *massage* it as you want.

If we considering the case when both values (ph, bh) may not be present simultaneously, then you would need a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You would need to create a new table and a sequence to produce the inserts, as in:

```
create table my_table (
  id int, 
  customer_id int, 
  validation_date date, 
  ph_value real, 
  bh_value real
);

create sequence seq1; -- a sequence is needed to generate IDs.
```

Then the query that could produce your data can look like:

```
insert into my_table (id, customer_id, validation_date, ph_value, bh_value) 
select
  next value for seq1,
  coalesce(ph.customer_id, bh.customer_id),
  coalesce(ph.validation_date, bh.validation_date),
  ph.amount,
  bh.amount
from (select * from t where test_type = 'ph') ph
full outer join (select * from t where test_type = 'bh') bh 
  on ph.customer_id = bh.customer_id 
 and ph.validation_date = bh.validation_date
```

Comment: thank you @the Impaler, I will give this a try, my limitiation is that I cant add extra tables, or temp tables into the SQL database. Will review how I can use this within my application and let you know

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to pivot the data:

```
select customer_id, validation_date,
       max(case when test_type = 'ph' then ph.test_result end) as ph_value,
       max(case when test_type = 'bh' then ph.test_result end) as bh_value
from t
group by customer_id, validation_date;
```

It is unclear where `itemid` comes from.  If calculated on the fly, I would suggest an `identity` column in the target table.

Then you can use either `SELECT . . . INTO` or `INSERT` to put the data in another table.